# Given a projection matrix $A$ can we prove that $\|Ax\|_2 < \|x\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a projection matrix $A$, can we prove/disprove that $\|Ax\|_2 < \|x\|_2$

Comment: What's your definition of a projection matrix? $A^2 = A$?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the matrix of an orthogonal projection, then
\begin{align}
\|x\|^2 & = \|Ax + (x-Ax)\|^2 \\[8pt]
\ge {} & \|Ax\|^2 + \|x-Ax\|^2 + 2\langle Ax, x-Ax\rangle \\[8pt]
= {} &  \|Ax\|^2 + \|x-Ax\|^2 \ge \|Ax\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: @N.S. : Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. For example, if $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 2 &1 \end{bmatrix}$ is a projection matrix.

Note that if $x= \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ then

$$\| x \|_2^2=a^2+b^2 \\
\| Ax \|_2 ^2=(2a+b)^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the example. If A is an orthogonal matrix, is this inequality true?

Comment: @shani If $A$ is orthogonal then $<Ax, x-Ax>=0$ and hence, by Pytagora's theorem $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2$. You cannot get strict inequality since for $x=Ay$ you have $Ax=x$.

Comment: @N.S. : Proper notation is $\langle Ax,x-Ax\rangle,$ not $<Ax,x-Ax>. \qquad $

Comment: @shani : I have to suspect you meant "If $A$ is the matrix of an orthogonal projection" rather than "If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix." Ever since the 19th century, the term "orthogonal matrix" means something else.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I was referring orthogonal matrix. Thanks for point it.